# WCF Service return a no-serializable object

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I set up a WCF Service like this:

IService1.cs

```
namespace AzureWebServiceTest
{    
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void createCloudAccount(string accountName);

        [OperationContract]
        SqlConnection useDb();
    }
}
```

Service1.cs

```
namespace AzureWebServiceTest
{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void createCloudAccount(string accountName)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(accountName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public SqlConnection useDb()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=StilistaLibrary;Trusted_Connection=true";
        return conn;
    }
}
}
```

But i have a problem with the return type of useDB(), i think because SqlConnection is a no-serializable object, how can i set up correctly this service?

Comment: Remove [OperationContract] from the useDb. You do not want to expose that method as an operation contract.

Comment: If I remove [Operation contract] that method will can not be used by those who use the service , right?

Comment: You are right that the SqlConnection is not serializable. The object represents a connection from the application (service) to a database. The connection is not transferable to a client which calls the service. What you could do, if you really need it, is send the connection string to the calling client. and let the client make the SqlConnection.

Comment: But in that case the service becomes useless , is not it ?

Comment: Depends on what you actually need.

Comment: I need to set up a Web Service for the client who need to work with a specific database.

Comment: Like i said, if you need the service to return information to a client about which database to use. You could better change the useDB method to return a string containing information about which database the client should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstand what you would introduce a web service for.

You certainly *don't* return database connection objects from the service to the client. You use a service to encapsulate and abstract the database from the client instead.

You add methods like `GetRecordsForCustomer(int customerID)` to the service, and let the client call that. You don't return database objects, but data contracts from the service.

This way you can not only change the underlying data store (i.e. swap databases, or more common, alter your data model without impacting your clients), but you can also add additional behavior without *having* to program triggers and procedures on the database.

If you instead want your clients to access the database directly, you have no use for a web service.